# In the main panel,brk. Size for sub panel

Tags: wiring

Sub panel is 35 feet from main panel in attached garage. 2 feeders are 4 awg.EV charger hardwired &plug circuits. Can I use 100 amp brk. in main panel, what size for neutral 4 or 6, ground 6 or 8

Comment: 2 feeders? A feeder is defined in the NEC as " All circuit conductors between the service equipment, the source of a separately derived system, or other power supply source and the final branch-circuit overcurrent device". So a feeder is a set of wires that include the neutral.

Comment: Can you post photos of your existing main panel please, for starters?

Comment: Pls [edit] 2 us ful wrds. ltrs r chep

Answer (score 1):

#4 copper is only 85A wire.  If you heard it was 100A, you're reading the wrong table, or the person whose word you took was reading the wrong table.

The right table is 310.16, and you use the 60C column for Type UF (as shown) and also for Type NM aka "Romex" (because of NEC 334.80).   All other cable types use the 75C column.  The 90C column is unavailable for consumer-tier panels (the kind that cost under $2000).

But nobody uses #4 copper anyway, as it's pointlessly expensive, and #2 aluminum is a commodity size at 90A that will carry 5 amps more at 1/3 the price.  Aluminum in these large sizes is proven safe.

If you are committed to 100A, use #1 aluminum or #3 copper.  However, don't fall for the common novice mistake of thinking you NEED a 50 amp circuit (or worse, two for two cars!) simply to charge at home.  EVs take a lot of power, *but not that much* - most people's needs come nowhere near what a 20A/240V circuit can deliver, and you can run that with cheap 12/2 Romex (EVs don't use neutral).   We often see people sink a lot of money into 50 amp circuits when they drive 17 miles a day, and it's wasted.

In fact, watch Technology Connections' excellent video on home charging. 28:15 gets right into level 2 charge station sizing.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Iyp_X3mwE1w

Now your neutral wire needs to be the same size as the hot wires. If you're not liking the cost of that, go all-aluminum.

The ground wire can be 8 AWG copper or 6 AWG aluminum up to 100A.

Generally, novices go straight for a large RV plug, thinking this cheaper or mandatory.  It is not.  Installing a socket requires GFCI protection, and that's a $130 breaker typically.  Also, our experience is that "cheapie" range sockets in the sub-$30 price range tend to melt down after some days of operation.  We strongly recommend the Hubbell/Bryant "RV park grade" receptacle, $50-100.  When you add the cost of a typically $300 "travel unit", you haven't really saved any money vs. a $400 wall unit like a Wallbox, Grizzl-E, etc.

You also need to do a service Load Calculation on the house, to assure it can support the additional load of EV charging.  If that's a problem, for a few hundred dollars more, you can get a wall unit capable of EVEMS, which takes care of provisioning problems.

Answer (score 0):

First step is  to determine if you have capacity to add a large subpanel by completing a "load calc" as defined in the NEC. If you don't have available capacity you won't get inspection approval.

The maximum best case scenario (75°C rated wiring) #4 copper is 85A with a maximum allowed overcurrent protection of 90A. If 60°C conditions exist then it must be protected at no more than 70A.

Not knowing plug configurations I would not recommend reducing neutral size.

#8 copper would be adequate for the ground.

Comment: Pretty sure per 250.102(C)(1) neutral can be #8 if the only big load is the EVSE and there's only a couple of 120V circuits, since EV charging is a balanced load.

Comment: @KMJ I think you crossed up reference, 250.102 is supply side of service. Relevant  section is 220 Branch-circuit, **feeder**, and service **load calculations**, 220.61 Feeder and Service Neutral Load. This section is one that seems to trigger inspectors. That section stipulates sized for "maximum unbalanced load". If inspectors look and for instance see the top 6 breaker spaces with 1p20 breakers and the evse below the inspector could turn off circuits 3 and 4 and say 1,2,5,6 create an imbalance, no-go, you need an 80A neutral.

Comment: Entirely possible I mixed it up, it's not somewhere I go very often. I did also say a couple of 120V circuits. If they go for a full shop, yeah, full sized neutral is needed for sure.